# Performance difference exporting a Virtualbox VM to VMWare

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-workstation

Is there any performance difference at all (CPU, RAM, DISK) if you export a Virtualbox VM and import it to VMWare Workstation? 
Also an other question is, VMWare in general should be faster for Virtualization than VBox right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean CPU for Intel VM on Intel host, then both should be just about the
same speed.

Both will execute instructions on the local CPU, with no emulation of instructions,
so the speed will depend only on the CPU.

Differences may also depend on the number of CPUs and amount of RAM
allocated to the VM.

If the VM principally uses devices such as the disk, rather than the CPU,
then Windows Hyper-V should be the best with its Generation 2 VMs,
whose drivers integrate more smoothly with the physical Windows drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My first server was with an Intel CPU, my new one is a AMD Ryzen. Its the same ram and cpu allocated. Everything is the same since its just an export import. So supposedly there shouldnt be any performance difference.

Comment: Comparing Intel with AMD is a long story, but in a nutshell: They are not comparable. See [article1](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/cpu-hierarchy,4312.html) and [article2](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/amd-vs-intel/). Performance doesn't depend here on Virtualbox or VMWare, but, as remarked in my answer, on the CPU and the type of load/operations that you place on it.